# VUE3: Property ... was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Hello I'm writing a simple Vue.js app and I want to use the `v-for` directive on the component `HelloWorld` using data from my items array.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
  <HelloWorld
    v-for="(item, index) in items"
    :key="index"
    :title="item.title"
    :msg="item.msg"
  />
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  data() {
    let items = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
      items.push({ title: `Test ${index}`, msg: `Test msg ${index}` });
    }
    return items;
  },
};
</script>
```

This is the error that I get:

`Property "items" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.  at <App>`

How can I fix this? I tried using `setup()` and `ref` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should return `items` as nested value of an object :

```
  data() {
    let items = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
      items.push({ title: `Test ${index}`, msg: `Test msg ${index}` });
    }
    return {
         items,
         //other properties
      };
  },
```